# recursively call in c to create link list

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

I am new in c so any help will be appreciated. I need to print 10 numbers from a linked list (it doesnt matter which numbers for now) I believe my code will print 9,8,7...0. for example. The linked list will be part of a struct (struct data) that will contain other variables (not important for now)

```
//linked list
struct listOfNodes {
    struct node *root;
};

//list of parameters to send to the function to print nodes
struct data {
    struct listOfNodes *list;
    int total;
};
```

I need to send the struct (struct data) as a parameter of a recursive function (addNode). In this recursive function, I need to add a new node to the linked list and call recursively 10 times to create more nodes for the link list, then I need to print the linked list. I have the following code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//node
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

//linked list
struct listOfNodes {
    struct node *root;
};

//list of parameters to send to the function to print nodes
struct data {
    struct listOfNodes *list;
    int total;
};

void printNode(struct listOfNodes *list) {
    struct node *n = list->root;

    while(n!=NULL){
        printf("%d\n",n->value);
        n=n->next;
    }
}

void addNode(void* d){   //parameter needs to be a void*

    struct data *o = (struct data *)d ;
    if(o->total<10) {
        //create new node
        struct node *n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        n->value = o->total;
        n->next = NULL;
        o->total = o->total + 1;
        if(o->list->root == NULL)
        {
            o->list->root = n;
        }
        else {
            n->next = o->list->root->next;
            o->list->root->next = n;
        }
        addNode(d);
    }

}

int main() {
    struct data *d= malloc(sizeof(struct data *));
    d->total=0;
    d->list=NULL;
    addNode(d); //add recursively 10 times
    if(d->list!=NULL) printNode(d->list);
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting Segmentation fault (core dumped). Can you please help me?

Comment: You are overcomplicating things with 2 structs. You can combine the 2 into one. Anyway, I don't see where you initialize `root = NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

In your main program, you added list as NULL. But in your addNode, you only check if list->root is NULL. What's happening is when

```
if(o->list->root == NULL)
        {
            o->list->root = n;
        }
```

is accessing list->root when list is NULL. You de reference a NULL pointer and segfault.

You probably need

```
struct listOfNodes *variable=malloc(sizeof(struct listOfNodes));
d->list=variable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes are describe in comments

```
#include <stdio.h>
// #include <string.h>  // <------- 4  not needed.
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {//node
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

struct listOfNodes {//linked list
    struct node *root;
};

struct data {//list of parameters to send to the function to print nodes
    struct listOfNodes *list;
    int total;
};

void printNode(struct listOfNodes *list) {
    struct node *n = list->root;

    while(n!=NULL){
        printf("%d\n",n->value);
        n=n->next;
    }
}

void addNode(struct data * d){  // <------- 3 no need to be void *  so o replaced by d
    if(d->total<10) {
        //create new node
        struct node *n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        n->value = d->total;
        n->next = NULL;
        d->total = d->total + 1;
        if(d->list->root == NULL)
        {
            d->list->root = n;
        }
        else {
            n->next = d->list->root->next;
            d->list->root->next = n;
        }
        addNode(d);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct data *d= malloc(sizeof(struct data));  // <---- 1 allocate data size not pointer size.
    d->total=0;
    d->list = malloc(sizeof(struct listOfNodes)); // <---- 2 alocate list !
    d->list->root = NULL;                         // <---- 2 init root.
    
    addNode(d); //add recursively 10 times
    if(d->list!=NULL) printNode(d->list);
    return 0;
}
```